# Form is not defined VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to store an form object into a variable, but it not succeed:

This code doesn't work:

```
Dim invoice_form As billing_new_invoice

    'Get last remote Row
    Dim last_row As Integer = CType(main.ActiveMdiChild, invoice_form).invoiceitems_new_invoice.Rows.Count - 1

    Dim count_row As Integer = CType(main.ActiveMdiChild, invoice_form).invoiceitems_new_invoice.Rows.Count()
```

This code works:

```
Dim invoice_form As billing_new_invoice

    'Get last remote Row
    Dim last_row As Integer = CType(main.ActiveMdiChild, billing_new_invoice).invoiceitems_new_invoice.Rows.Count - 1

    Dim count_row As Integer = CType(main.ActiveMdiChild, billing_new_invoice).invoiceitems_new_invoice.Rows.Count()
```

[image: Error]

I need to store the form instance in the variable (invoice_form), that could be used in multiple lines of code, but it says (Type 'invoice_form' is not defined.)
Anyone have idea to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very clear what the issue is.  I think you are looking for something like this:

```
If TypeOf Me.ActiveMdiChild Is billing_new_invoice Then
  Dim invoice_Form As billing_new_invoice = Me.ActiveMdiChild

  Dim last_row As Integer = invoice_form.invoiceitems_new_invoice.Rows.Count - 1
  Dim count_row As Integer = invoice_form.invoiceitems_new_invoice.Rows.Count()

  //'etc

End If
```

The problem with the code that isn't working is that it is trying to cast it into a variable, not a type.  `invoice_form` is a variable, `billing_new_invoice` is a type.

Answer (score 2):

CType is for type conversion, not variable assignment. What you want to do is assign the variable to the form first, then use that variable:

```
Dim invoice_form As billing_new_invoice = CType(main.ActiveMdiChild, billing_new_invoice)
Dim last_row As Integer = invoice_form.invoiceitems_new_invoice.Rows.Count - 1
```